# Dynamic request's parameters in a Rest WS

Tags: java, rest, http, request, cypher

I'v been asked to implement a request for a REST Web Service, with dynamic parameters. I'll explain with an example:
now our request object's fields are three strings, which are taken from the controller and used to realize the business logic. Tomorrow, we may have the need to introduce another parameter, so I'v been suggested to implement the request object with a Map, so that we can manage more than 3 properties in the request, without opening the code and having to re-deploy the service.

Now, my question is, is this possible? I think it is, but anyways the controller will not know what to do with the newly inserted properties, or maybe it will never use it! So, IMHO, this is a useless rework, because we will need to open the code and redeploy the .war anyhow.

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S. The web service is a wrapper for GraphDB calls, if it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **GET** method, you can get parameter names to values as shown in below snippet:

```
@GET
public String get(@Context UriInfo ui) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ui.getQueryParameters();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParams = ui.getPathParameters();
}
```

For **Form parameters** it is possible to do the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
    // Store the message
}
```

By using **MultivaluedMap**, you can pass any parameters to the Rest service and you can process your business logic.

Reference: [Extracting request params](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrst/)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good implementation for what I need. But I failed to explain my main doubt, sorry.
If I implement this kind of request, when one day I'll need to introduce another properties to my request, will I need to open the code? Or do I need just to add the properties to my request?

Thanks again

Comment: If you add the properties at your client, you should definitely change the code at client... As you are not using any DTO, if nothing effects the service, you'll not change the service end.. only you'll change the required service method and its business logic.